# Why is typescript inferring my dynamic key is a function that returns an object

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

const a = {
something: true,
};

return

```
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={
          a["Some Thing".toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, "") as keyof boolean]
        }
      />
```

I get a typescript error Type '() => Object' is not assignable to type 'boolean | undefined'

tried googling, wasnt able to find anything with this particular attribute. The only solution I could find was hard coding everything

Comment: `keyof boolean` yields a type of `"valueOf"` and the type of `Object.valueOf` is `() => Object`. This is the danger of manual type assertion.

Comment: `const n = {b: 1, c: 's'}['c' as 'b']` yields `n: number`

Comment: Yeah, is this just a typo?  `keyof boolean` is essentially nonsense (I mean, have you ever seen someone write `(true).valueOf()`?)

Comment: It does feels like typo, probably the intended use case is to do `a["Some Thing".toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, "")] as boolean`...

Answer (score 2):

[The `keyof` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator) takes a type and returns the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of its key types.  The type `keyof boolean` would therefore be the type of keys you could use to index *into* a value of type `boolean`.  You almost certainly don't mean this; nobody indexes into a `boolean` as if it were an object.  Let's see what `keyof boolean` is:

```
type KeyofBoolean = keyof boolean;
// type KeyofBoolean = "valueOf"
```

Ah, that makes sense; the compiler only knows of [the `valueOf` property of the autoboxed `Boolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean/valueOf).  So you can write this if you want to:

```
const b = (true).valueOf(); // boolean
```

Not that you would want to. So then,

```
"Some Thing".toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, "") as keyof boolean
```

is the same as saying

```
"Some Thing".toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, "") as "valueOf"
```

So the compiler thinks you're writing

```
a["valueOf"]
```

or

```
a.valueOf
```

[which exists and it's a function that returns an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf), or `() => Object`.  And the compiler complains that the `checked` attribute of an `input` probably shouldn't be a function that returns an object.

Oops.

---

So `keyof boolean` is essentially a mistake or a typo; you were presumably trying to say that it was a key of `a`, which has type `typeof a` (using [the `typeof` type query operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html)):

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  checked={
    a["Some Thing".toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, "") as keyof typeof a]
  }
/> // okay
```

I'm not sure if this question needs a full answer like this, or just someone to point out "hey that's a typo".  Either way I wanted to be sure this was made clear.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgGklqJMAhCCAG1QDs4AvHADWzVnABGnHil4UA9PLg06jMe2l9BcAEQA3FFwCuSAPKYdlNBF4BneBO0AKGFBMBKAHQHjZzE-dSOEVJTVkrG3s4FG0AbzhbXCQYAAtgXgBzAC5lNyQAGjgAXwpKcgAedLAjGHI4ZVokAR00FKQ0YSkAD0t61vbRABMBWLr66IBtHQBlJLgAFTTMnU8YCAAZCAB3JCgAYRRbJADPIjAudGP5AB1bAGp5DMKdHXdo2xF1BrpxFABdMZFcjyAB8wSUEGEKGo5CAA)

Answer (score 0):

It seems I have answered the question a bit too fast. The error message mentioned in the question is caused by incorrect type assertion, as explained in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76134125/8888888) by [@jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz). However, this answer is still useful as it explains why that type assertion is needed in the first place.

---

When you try the following code:

```
a["Some Thing".toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, "")]
```

you get a type error because `a` only has a property named `"something"`, and the return type of `.toLowerCase()` and `.replace(...)` is `string`, not `"something"`. Unfortunately, TypeScript does not produce a [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html) when you call string methods on a string literal. However, there are a few solutions you can try:

1. Use the [Template Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) feature to make your own string manipulation function that does return a literal type:

```js
type Whitespace = ' ' | '\n' | '\t' | '\r' | '\f';
type TrimAllWhitespace<S extends string> =
  S extends `${Whitespace}${infer Rest}`
    ? TrimAllWhitespace<Rest>
    : S extends `${infer NonWhitespace}${infer Rest}`
    ? `${NonWhitespace}${TrimAllWhitespace<Rest>}`
    : '';

function convert<T extends string>(x: T): TrimAllWhitespace<Lowercase<T>> {
  return x.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '') as TrimAllWhitespace<Lowercase<T>>;
}

const a = { something: true };

const App = () => <input type="checkbox" checked={a[convert('Some Thing')]} />;
```

2. Force typecast to something that you already know:

```js
const a = { something: true };

const App = () => (
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    checked={
      a['Some Thing'.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '') as keyof typeof a]
    }
  />
);
```

3. Use a more relax typing at the variable `a`

```js
const a: Record<string, boolean | undefined> = { something: true };

const App = () => (
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    checked={a['Some Thing'.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '')]}
  />
);
```

Comment: Presumably they already expect to have to type assert, but are asserting to `keyof boolean` for some unknown reason, which is causing the problem.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was unconstructive and uncouth. But OP's question was essentially "why does this return a type of `() => Object`". I downvoted your post because it failed to answer that, and started with what I consider an unrelated distraction. I could see a beginner wasting hours trying to understand your metaprogramming.

Still, your post could be helpful if you actually answered the question first, and then clarified that the reason you need a type assertion is because `.toLowerCase().replace()` have a return type of `string` and `a` is an Object instead of a `Record`.

Comment: HI @Domino, thanks for the constructive feedback. I just noticed about it after jcalz commented in the question. I don't feel it is right for me to claim credit and change my answer based on that comment, thus I didn't modify my answer further. Either way, I have modified my answer to point it back to jcalz's answer so it is clearer to the OP

Comment: I've added the clarifications I mentioned in my comment. Feel free to rephrase it if you're uncomfortable with my edit, I always feel awkward editing someone's answer when it's written in the 1st-person.

Comment: @Domino thank you so much! Sorry for the trouble and thanks for being helpful.